# Move from Apache FtpServer to SFTP

Tags: ftp, sftp, sshd, apache-mina, ftp-server

I have configured the Apache FTPServer using the xml configuration on my server. Right now it is FTP but i want to change it to SFTP. How should i go about this transition. I want to move my existing users as to the new sftp server.

Comment: SFTP (SSH) or FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL)?

Comment: SFTP(SSH) not FTPS @MartinPrikryl

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy transition. You have to start from a scratch with a different implementation.

[Apache FtpServer](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/) does not support SFTP.

You can use another Apache Mina project, [Apache SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/), which supports SFTP.

Comment: i have some front end functionalities based on the existing FTP tables used by apache FTPServer, not sure how to move those to Apache SSHD. I dont think SSHD uses the same table like functionality

Comment: *"Frontend"* to what? What *"FTP tables"*? - If you have a specific problem with the transition, ask a specific question. There's hardly more to be added to this broad one.

Comment: i have made a web app that provides functionality of adding,deleting and updating the user directories etc such kind of functionalities. If i start with a implementation using apache SSHD, will i be able to do all these things ?

Comment: Again, if you have a specific problem with the transition, ask a new specific question. And be clear, because I have no idea what you ask about.

Comment: Sure Thanks will look into it